# How to set caret position of a contenteditable div containing combination of text and element nodes

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

My HTML:

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">abcd<img src="icon.gif"/>efgh</div>
```

My `caret = 5;` so I want to set the caret poisition to be immediately after the image as the image is treated as 1 character.

So I wrote thise code:

```
var node = document.querySelector("div");
node.focus();
var textNode = node.firstChild;
var caret = 5; 
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(textNode, caret);
range.setEnd(textNode, caret);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 5 is larger than or equal to the node's length (4).

Please suggest how I might achieve this ? I might have several images before the caret position I desire and each image would be treated as 1 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `textNode` has 3 children (1 text, 1 element, 1 text) and therefore you can't just use `firstChild`.

You need to iterate over the `childNodes` of the `<div>` and track the character count where the `nodeType` of the `childNode` equals `Node.TEXT_NODE` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) on MDN). Where the character count is less than the value of `caret` you can deduct that from `caret` and move onto the next text node.

Per your condition that:

> I desire and each image would be treated as 1 character

The code will deduct 1 from `caret` where `nodeType == 1` i.e. `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`

Here is a code example with multiple icons:

```js
var node = document.querySelector("div");
node.focus();
var caret = 24; 

var child;
var childNodeIndex = 0;
for(var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++) {
  child = node.childNodes[i];
  // Node.ELEMENT_NODE == 1
  // Node.TEXT_NODE == 3
  if(child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    // keep track of caret across text childNodes
    if(child.length <= caret) {
      caret -= child.length;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  } else if (child.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    // condition that 'each image would be treated as 1 character'
    if(caret > 0) {
      caret -= 1;
    } else {
     break;
    }
  };
  childNodeIndex += 1;
}

var textNode = node.childNodes[childNodeIndex];

// your original code continues here...
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(textNode, caret);
range.setEnd(textNode, caret);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">a<img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/><img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/><img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/><img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/>b<img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/>cdefghijkl<img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/>mnopq<img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/>rst<img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/>uvw<img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/>xyz<img src="https://www.splitbrain.org/_static/ico/circular/ico/add.png"/></div>
```